# what is native memory or c-heap

Tags: java, c, memory, jvm, heap-memory

I tried to explore on this but could not find a answer which has included basics in it.

I want to know the types of memory consumption done by JVM or a java program like heap memory , native memory etc.

But I would also like to know that what is this native memory which is also known as C-heap.

I am looking for explanation which includes very basics in it.

Comment: I just deleted my answer and vote to close here. It's either answered in two sentences or *much* too broad. And it's even unclear what exactly you're after.

Answer (score 4):

Java programs run in a virtualized environment of the Java runtime. This run time in itself is a native process(just like any other process). So, the restrictions of the native memory are imposed by the hardware and the operating system that the processes run on.

All modern operating systems use virtual memory where each running program is assigned its own virtual address space, size of which is dictated by the underlying architecture. For an Intel x86-32-bit architecture, the maximum available address space is 2^32 - 1, which equals to 4GB. Even though a process has its own virtual space, it cant use all of it. This virtual space is divided into Kernel and User space. On Windows OS running on x86-32, 2GB is reserved for user space and 2GB for kernal space and on Linux, its 3GB to 1GB.

For a Java process, the user space can be logically divided into heap memory* and native memory. Size of heap memory is dictated by "Xms, Xmx". There are no options with which you can manage the native memory as this is done by the JRE for you. It is always a best practice to constantly check the native memory consumption and detect leaks before your application dies with an OutOfMemoryException. **Heap memory is just the portion of user space managed by JVM.**

Comment: I dont want the details how the memories are allocated, Instead I want that what is native memory

Comment: @HimJEL then phrase your question accordingly instead of downvoting a valid answer.

Comment: Actually you are asking for explanation.